# Emacs doesn't open at macOS Big Sur 11.3.1

Tags: osx, install

I tried to install Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/ and also with brew. In both cases I get the following error if I wanna open the GUI:

> “Emacs” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

I tried

`brew cask reinstall emacs --no-quarantine`

from https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/87415 but it still doesn't work. Has anyone help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error running emacs on macOS big sur, "because Apple cannot check it for malicious software"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68615/error-running-emacs-on-macos-big-sur-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicio)

Comment: @NickD I finally solved the issue with getting version 27.2-2 from https://emacsformacosx.com/builds. I also tried the solutions from your post but this didn't work. Thanks.